# PowerPoint COM Component Security Issue - IIS vs Web Development Server

Tags: security, deployment, iis-7, com, powerpoint

Scenario is running fine when I use my web service to run on default asp.net development server but when is use IIS 7.0 to host my service then problem is raised:

## My Problem is:

I have run in to a few problems, for one when I try to run the PowerPoint within my C# program with `Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint`. 
Initially I am getting access denied problem at the following lines of code:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application oPowerPointApplication = 
    new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentation oPpt = 
    oPowerPointApplication.Presentations.Add(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse);
```

So I have given permissions in DCOM config. that solved the problem but after that when I use SaveAs method with following code:

```
oPpt.SaveAs(@szPPTFile, 
    PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsPresentation,
    Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse);
```

then I got 2 errors:

1. Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
2. Presentation (unknown member) : An error occurred while PowerPoint was saving the file.

I have tried many solutions suggested by different Individuals on internet but did not able to resolve this. please help!

Regards, 
Zeeshan Mahmood

Comment: Usually when you cannot save the problem is related to file permission or file opened for reading and not disposed.